# Random URL redirect from array

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome-extension, hyperlink

/**
 *  Political Animals
 *  contentscript.js is loaded on each page(s) listed in manifest.json
 *     This plugin replaces all the images on the website of news sites with pictures of 
 *      animals in suits, as a commentary on what the news has become. Made for Web 2
 *      November 20, 2013
 */

//Random Image array

```
var arrayImg = ['http://www.whattofix.com/images/PoliticalAnimal.jpg','http://www.fubiz.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Fashion-Zoo-Animals26.jpeg','http://img1.etsystatic.com/016/1/7647665/il_340x270.411173311_ojy5.jpg','http://ny-image0.etsy.com/il_fullxfull.85564656.jpg','http://afraidofmice.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/berkleyill.jpg','http://elizabethmarshallgalleryblog.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/etsy-panda-for-blog1.jpg','http://moesewco.typepad.com/.a/6a00e5500684b488330120a5c7cf3a970c-300wi','http://ih3.redbubble.net/image.13276877.5059/flat,800x800,070,f.u1.jpg','http://www.tildeshop.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/SeaLionFemale-21.jpg'];
```

//redirect

```
var acceptedWebsites =['www.cnn.com', 'www.nytimes.com', 'www.latimes.com', 'www.washingtonpost.com', 'www.nbcnews.com', 'www.foxnews.com'];
var currentUrl = document.location.href;
var referrer =  currentUrl.match(/:\/\/(.[^/]+)/)[1];
```

//Making sure the code does what I want it to. As long as the link shows a number greater than -1, then the site extension is working
    console.log(referrer);
    console.log(acceptedWebsites.indexOf(referrer));

//var url = acceptedWebsites[Math.floor(Math.random()*acceptedWebsites.length)];
//document.location.href = url;

// image source goes through the following script function
    $('img').each(function(){

// creating the randomizing

```
var random = arrayImg[Math.floor(Math.random()*arrayImg.length)];
//Takes the current array and applies the source with the random function
$(this).attr('src', random);
//removing the stretch
 var theWidth = $(this).width();
            var theHeight = $(this).height();
            if (theWidth < theHeight) {
                $(this).height(150);
            }
            else {
                $(this).width(150);
            }
});
```

//alert ("Go to any of the follow websites: fox.com, nbc.com, nytimes.com, latimes.com, or cnn.com");

I have this array in javascript. I want to have it so that the user is automatically redirected to one of the links from the array, possibly randomly. I don't know if I can do this in javascript. I am using this for a chrome extension, so I don't know if I can use php.

These are fantastic answers, except they constantly redirect. I want it so that they are just redirected to one from the array once, not constantly redirect.

**Edit 2: I added my whole code because something is causing there to be a constant redirect instead of only once.

**Edit 3: I updated my code. The console.log proves that my new variables work and do ==-1. How can I use them to redirect?

Comment: Just get a random index from the array and boom, there's your URL.

Comment: No, you can't use PHP directly in Chrome Extensions - only HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Comment: Is this an extension that gets loaded on **every** page load?

Comment: On only the redirected page.

Comment: @twario I don't get it... You want to redirect the user to a website in this list when he is already on a website of the list?

Comment: Ok, I see the confusion. I think this may require an if/else statement. I want to redirect him if he isn't on the page. If he is, then the other stuff

Comment: You're redirecting the user on every page, causing an endless loop of redirects, how about checking if the current page is in the array, and if not, then redirect.

Answer (score 3):

Get a random URL from the array, and redirect ?

```
if ( acceptedWebsites.indexOf(document.location.href) == -1 ) {
    var url = acceptedWebsites[Math.floor(Math.random()*acceptedWebsites.length)];
    document.location.href = url;
}
```

Comment: This redirects constantly. It doesn't stop.

Comment: @twario That doesn't make any sense. There is no loop that repeats these lines. Even if there was, as soon as the location has been changed, the script execution stops. You did something wrong, somewhere.

Comment: Can you add code and comment the way to check if a person is using a site from the array?

Comment: @twario - something like the above code, but the adress has to match exactly what is in the array, so you might have to do some parsing to get it right, hard to tell.

Comment: I edited my code to update it. How can I get this to relate to my new code?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var acceptedWebsites =['http://www.cnn.com/', 'www.nytimes.com', 'www.latimes.com', 'http://www.washingtonpost.com/', 'http://www.nbcnews.com/', 'http://www.foxnews.com/'];
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * acceptedWebsites.length);
```

number will generate a random number between 1 and the number of entries in your acceptedwebsites array.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location = acceptedWebsites[Math.floor(Math.random() * acceptedWebsites.length)];
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic jist of the logic would be...

```
var acceptedWebsites = ['http://www.cnn.com/', 'www.nytimes.com', 'www.latimes.com', 'http://www.washingtonpost.com/', 'http://www.nbcnews.com/', 'http://www.foxnews.com/'];

var randomLink = Math.floor(Math.random() * acceptedWebsites.length);

window.location = acceptedWebsites[randomLink];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get random site
var randomSite = acceptedWebsites[Math.floor(Math.random() * acceptedWebsites.length)];

// redirect to selected site
window.location = randomSite;
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate a "random" key and use `window.location.href` to redirect the user. Others have posted the same approach, though with less explanation. I'm giving my best to let you actually understand what happens here.

Note that most of this code is comments. It looks longer than it actually is.

```
var acceptedWebsites = ['http://www.cnn.com/', 'www.nytimes.com', 'www.latimes.com', 'http://www.washingtonpost.com/', 'http://www.nbcnews.com/', 'http://www.foxnews.com/'];

// This function returns a random key for an array
function randomKey(arr) {
    // Math.random() returns a number between 0 and 0.99999...
    // If you multiply this value with the length of an array, you get a
    // random floating point number between 0 and that length.
    // Use Math.floor() to round it down to the next integer
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
}

// Select a random website from the array
var key = randomKey(acceptedWebsites);
var newLocation = acceptedWebsites[key];

// Redirect the user
window.location.href = newLocation;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
var size = acceptedWebsites.length;

var x = Math.floor((Math.random()* size)+1);
```

Now use loop for value x-1 like

```
var location = acceptedWebsites[x-1];
window.location.href = location;
```

If we run this in loop ,we will get different value of x every time between 0-size of array and then we can use that random value to randomly redirect.

Comment: Why exactly do you first add 1 and then subtract 1?

Comment: suppose u get value .9 from Math.random() so * size will give you 4.5.Now 4.5+1 give you 5.5.Then Math.floor will give you 5.If i does not add 1 in this case then i always get values from 1 to 4 and not 1 to 5(I am talking about array example given above).Below i am subtracting 1 because array starting index is 0.

Comment: If you don't add 1, you get values from 0 to 4, which is exactly what you need for an array length of 5.

Answer (score -1):

window.location doesn't work since content scripts are unprivileged. Further more, window.location.href returns the current location, but it is not a method so you cannot overwrite it.

you'll need to:

Send redirect url from a content script to a background page:

```
var url = acceptedWebsites[Math.floor(Math.random()*acceptedWebsites.length)];
chrome.extension.sendRequest({redirect: url });
```

In a background page update tab's url which would cause redirect:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender) {
    chrome.tabs.update(sender.tab.id, {url: request.redirect});
});
```

Comment: The top of this answer is wrong, content scripts can freely write to `location.href` if they wish.