# Redirect to random webpage when a video has ended

Tags: javascript, redirect, video, random

I'm a bit of a coding novice but I am trying to put something together for a project I am working on.

What I want is for the webpage to load, play a video and then when the video ends then to redirect to one of 7 possible pages.

At the moment I have two separate bits of code for both of these functions.

For the video load/play/redirect (at the moment it redirects to to google) I have this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"                                         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />


<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js"></script>


<!----<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="50;URL=http://www.flashybee.com/gaf/test">-->
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#000000">

<div align="center">
<video id="index_vid" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls autoplay preload="auto"         width="800" height="400" data-setup="{}">
<source src="index_vid.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
<source src="index_vid.webm" type='video/webm'>
</video>

<script type="text/javascript">
 _V_("index_vid").ready(function(){
var myPlayer = this;
myPlayer.play();
myPlayer.addEvent("ended", function(){
    window.location = "http://www.google.com"
});
});
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

For the random link I have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function randomlinks(){
var myrandom=Math.round(Math.random()*6)
var links=new Array()
links[0]="test1.html"
links[1]="test2.html"
links[2]="test3.html"
links[3]="test4.html"
links[4]="test5.html"
links[5]="test10.html"
links[6]="test11.html"

window.location=links[myrandom]
}
</script>


<form>
<input name="butt" type="button" id="butt" onClick="randomlinks()" value="random link!">
</form>
```

I can't work out how to fix these together to get what I need. I want the end of the video to trigger the random link and open it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random URL redirect from array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20100450/random-url-redirect-from-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, you just need to call the random link function you have from the event for the video ending.

```
myPlayer.addEvent("ended", function(){
    randomlinks();
});
```

or more succinctly

```
myPlayer.addEvent("ended", randomlinks);
```

Also you'll probably want to define the randomlinks function in the same script block for logic grouping.

Comment: Or more concise: `myPlayer.addEvent("ended", randomlinks);`